# Set SameSite for Cookie in Apex

Tags: security, cookies, session-cookies, apex, setcookie

As explained in https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/, Chrome will enable SameSite=lax by default if SameSite is not specified.

In Apex, we can set Cookie using `Cookie ck = new Cookie('cookieLabel','cookieValue',null,-1,false);`

How can I set `SameSite=None;Secure` for ck variable of Cookie class?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the [Apex Cookie Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm#apex_System_Cookie_methods) does not support the `SameSite` attribute at all.

As a result, I would investigate using [`HttpResponse.setHeader()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm#apex_System_HttpResponse_setHeader) directly:

```
httpResponse.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'cookieLabel=cookieValue; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

Be aware though, in other frameworks I do see the cookie handling overwrite any existing `Set-Cookie` headers so you may want to ensure you do any manual setting of headers either before or after the in-built cookie handling.

I would also raise a feature request for full support of the `SameSite` attribute in the framework.